# how to check lease expire and lease obtained information in Mac osx

Tags: mac-osx, bash, ip

How i can view the lease expire and lease obtained information in Max osx.
I know that i can check it in windows using ipconfig /all.
but ifconfig in mac does not give all this information. so where i can find this information in mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try "ipconfig getpacket en0"

(Yes, this is on OS X). Change en0 to whatever the number is of your network adapter (usually en0 for Ethernet, en1 for Airport, etc.) That should give you the DHCP info.

For general info, use the "networksetup" command (at various paths depending on OS X version).

See more options here:
http://aplawrence.com/MacOSX/ipconfig.html

Comment: no it does not show the lease expire and lease obtained information(dates)

Answer (score 1):

Look in /private/var/db/dhcpclient/leases